# can I manage with different site session data in one redis?

Tags: java, session, redis

I manage session data in a Redis server.  Our Redis server consists of a replica set and Master-Slave. One session data is related to our web site and the other elsewhere. For example, We have a plan to manage a mobile site and application. I want to manage two site session data in one Redis server and I want to know the source, is this possible?

Comment: Just use differently prefixed keys in Redis? Or a separate Redis "database" ?

Comment: @Thilo I think the best case is separate Redis database. I wonder one Redis server has a lot of different database. Each database is mapped with indepedent system. Is it possible??

Comment: They are just different namespaces. They still share the same server process and memory. If you need them to be independent, you can install multiple Redis processes (ideally on separate machines).